# angular/jasmine: Error: No deferred tasks to be flushed

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I'm unit testing one of my directives and I get the following error

```
Error: No deferred tasks to be flushed
```

The code I need to test is inside a $timeout

```
$timeout(function () {
    $window.doStuff();
});
```

So when I want to check if `doStuff` was called I do

```
$timeout.flush();
expect($window.doStuff).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

However, now I need to test a situation in which I don't expect `doStuff` to have been called. So I did:

```
$timeout.flush();
expect($window.doStuff).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // Notice the not here!!
```

However, because `$timeout` was not called, the `$timeout.flush()` gives me this error.

So the question is, what is the preferred way to test this situation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks()` to check if no tasks have been added.

Check angular documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout):

> Verifies that there are no pending tasks that need to be flushed.